# Userform Checkbox to Conditional Format Range

Tags: excel, vba

EDIT: Conditional Format Code is working for each condition individually, but not if both are conditions are met.  If both Conditions are met the only issue is column L doesn't highlight yellow:

```
'Conditional Format for ChiResident & Apprentice
Dim Cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition
Set Cond1 = Range("L" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlEqual, EmployeeInformation.ChiResident.Value = True)
Set cond2 = Range("L" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, x1equal, EmployeeInformation.Apprentice.Value = True)
With Cond1
.Font.Color = vbRed
.Font.Bold = True
End With
With cond2
.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
```

I Tried to get this to work a few ways but cannot seem to write the correct code.  Here is my last attempt.

```
  With Cond1 And Cond2
Range("L" & bot_row).Font.Color = vbRed And .Font.Bold = True And .Interior.Color = vbYellow
Range("M" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
```

Another attempt:

```
If Cond1 And Cond2 = True Then
Range("L" & bot_row).Font.Color = vbRed
Range("L" & bot_row).Font.Bold = True
Range("L" & bot_row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Range("M" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End If
```

Last attempt:

```
    'Conditional Format for ChiResident & Apprentice
Dim Cond1 As FormatCondition, Cond2 As FormatCondition, Cond3 As FormatCondition
Set Cond1 = Range("L" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlEqual, EmployeeInformation.ChiResident.Value = True)
Set Cond2 = Range("L" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, x1equal, EmployeeInformation.Apprentice.Value = True)
Set Cond3 = Range("L" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, xlEqual, EmployeeInformation.ChiResident.Value = True) And Range("M" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, x1equal, EmployeeInformation.Apprentice.Value = True)
With Cond1
.Font.Color = vbRed
.Font.Bold = True
End With
With Cond2
.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
With Cond3
Range("L" & bot_row).Font.Color = vbRed
Range("L" & bot_row).Font.Bold = True
Range("L" & bot_row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
Range("M" & bot_row & ":AB" & bot_row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End With
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

EDIT: Working code just had to stop if true.

```
 With Cond1
.Font.Color = vbRed
.Font.Bold = True
.StopIfTrue = False
End With
With Cond2
.Interior.Color = vbYellow
.StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

Comment: How are you running this code? What happens when you debug it? https://analystcave.com/how-to-debug-vba/

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx?em_x=22

Comment: I just put the full code into my original post.  I have currently removed the Attempt #1 and #2 code just so it works without the conditional format.  However, I am still working to figure this out.  I will take a look at your debug posts but I am pretty new to VBA.  Thanks!

Comment: You will need to `.Add` a format condition before calling upon it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add

Comment: That was a huge help thank you! I have put my new code under EDIT in the original post.  One other question is while I have this working for both individual conditions I cannot seem to get it to apply yellow fill in column L if both checkbox's are checked.  I tried `.priority` but it didn't seem to work. Curious if you have any other suggestions or can point me in the right direction.  Thanks again!

Comment: Avoid having too many overlapping formats. The `.Priority` does appear to be the correct way to order them. If you're setting the format with VBA you can remove all formatting and apply only the one you want. The way conditional formatting works, you don't need to use VBA. Just setup the rules manually and make sure they work that way before trying to make it happen with wizard magic.

Comment: I got it had to change code to not stop if true....  I was overthinking it thanks for all the pointers!

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer. This closes out the question and also gives you points!

Comment: thanks didn't realize I could do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code just had to stop if true.

```
 With Cond1
.Font.Color = vbRed
.Font.Bold = True
.StopIfTrue = False
End With
With Cond2
.Interior.Color = vbYellow
.StopIfTrue = False
End With
```